# Grammatik, Verwendung und Kasus? - "Der unnötige Begegnung vermeidet, hilft allen, ..."

Tags: sentence-structure, usage, grammatical-case, grammar-identification

An excerpt from Angela Merkel's televised speech regarding Covid-19, I'm trying to figure out the grammatical structure of the first clause: what are the cases used and could you provide another sentence with a similar grammatical structure? Thank you!

> **Der unnötige Begegnung vermeidet**, hilft allen, die sich in den Krankenhäusern um täglich mehr Fälle kümmern müssen, so retten wir Leben. ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgC2TzvIRY8&t=8m28s), TV-Ansprache der Kanzlerin vom 18.3.2020)

Comment: She says *wer*, but that doesn't change the grammatical structure, so I left *der* unedited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your transcription must be erroneous: I get ***Wer*** unnötige Begegnung vermeidet... when I Google. Admittedly, Merkel's pronunciation of the *w* is somewhat less than clear ([video at appropriate time](https://youtu.be/Slo4LHcrasg?t=573)).

Then this is a subjectival clause: the *wer...* clause is the subject of *hilft*.

"**Whoever avoids unnecessary contact** helps all, who..."

Comment: And *wer* is the subject of the embedded clause.

Comment: A maybe more literal translation: **He who** avoids unnecessary contact..."

Answer (score 3):

Nonwithstanding what Merkel actually said, the sentence as you wrote it is **is** grammatical.  *Der* can be used as a substitute for *der, welcher*, although that sounds rather old fashioned, even more so with the subordinated clause put at the beginning -- the formulation reminds me of biblical language.  And that's what makes it sound wrong in a context like this, where such a style is not expected.